# Neo4j Session.query() - How to map query response to Custom Java Object

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

### I have a Node Entity:

```
@NodeEntity(label = CollectionNames.CONSUMER)
public class Consumer extends AbstractNode{

    //Properties, removed just for simplicity

    @Relationship(type = RelationshipNames.HAS_CONTACT, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<HasContact> contactList;

//Constructor & Getters, Setters
}
```

### For Storing custom query results:

```
@QueryResult
public class CustomQueryResult {

    private AbstractNode node;
    private List<? extends AbstractRelationship> relationships;

    public CustomQueryResult(AbstractNode node, List<? extends AbstractRelationship> relationships){
        this.node = node;
        this.relationships = relationships;
    }

//Default Constructor, Getters & Setters
}
```

### Repository Implementation

```
String query = String.format(
                "MATCH (startNode:Consumer {mobileNumber : {mob}})-[rel:%s *%d..%d]->(endNode:%s) RETURN startNode as node, rel as relationships",
                relationshipName, 0, depth, endNode);
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("mob", mobileNo);
        CustomQueryResult consumer =  session.queryForObject(CustomQueryResult.class, query, params);
```

Although given Query load required data, but unfortunately its unable to map it to given Object(`CustomQueryResult`). But in case if I map it to `Consumer` then it show given error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Result not of expected size. Expected 1
>   row but found 6

While this same query is working fine, if I use Spring Data Neo4j Repository like

```
@Query("MATCH (startNode:Consumer {mobileNumber : {0}})-[rel:HAS_CONTACT *..1]->(endNode:Consumer) RETURN startNode as node, rel as relationships")
    CustomQueryResult findByMobileNumberAndRelationship(String mobileNo);
```

So how can I map given query result into `Consumer` or `CustomQueryResult` object directly?

Or is that possible to do the same thing using Spring Data Neo4j Repository with dynamic Relationship names and depth like:

```
@Query("MATCH (startNode:Consumer {mobileNumber : {0}})-[rel:{1} *..{2}]->(endNode:Consumer) RETURN startNode as node, rel as relationships")
    CustomQueryResult findByMobileNumberAndRelationship(String mobileNo, String relationshipName, @Depth int depth);
```

Although I am sure that above code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns multiple rows

```
MATCH (startNode:Consumer {mobileNumber : {0}})-[rel:HAS_CONTACT *..1]->(endNode:Consumer) 
RETURN startNode as node, rel as relationships
```

where `node` is repeated for each `rel`. The repository infrastructure is able to handle that, but `queryForObject` is not - it expects single row.

It should work if you modify your query in following way so it returns only 1 row:

```
MATCH (startNode:Consumer {mobileNumber : {0}})-[rel:HAS_CONTACT *..1]->(endNode:Consumer) 
RETURN startNode as node, COLLECT(rel) as relationships
```